# Implementation of putc in Versatile ARM LATEST Kernel-4.6

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, arm, embedded-linux

I am Trying to understand How linux printing

```
"Uncompressing Linux....... done, booting the kernel"
```

message even before it uncompressed itself in ARM Versatile Boad.

From this [File](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/boot/compressed/misc.c)  the function decompress_kernel is writing the message through  putstr() function which inturn have putc function which writing to hardware register uart.

putc is implemented in [this](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/mach-versatile/include/mach/uncompress.h?v=4.4#L28)  file, putc writes directly to  *AMBA_UART_DR* registers and these registers are different across architectures and also differs across different chips too.

But in the latest kernel-4.6 [this](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/mach-versatile/include/mach/uncompress.h?v=4.4) was deprecated .
When i checked putc implemetation for ARM Versatile Boad in latest kernel its been deprecated so

how they implemented in latest kernel-4.6 where as rest of [machine-specific](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=putc) code still exist?

```
How kernel is printing the banner in latest kernel?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Versatile board support code was converted to the multi-platform kernel model (ARCH_MULTIPLATFORM). Just like every other board support code of the same kind, now it takes putc() prototype from arch/arm/include/debug/uncompress.h.

Instead, the actual implementation of putc() is a generic assembly function coded into arch/arm/boot/compressed/debug.S.

Being generic, debug.S makes reference to few macros (addruart, waituart, senduart, busyuart) to get information about the actual UART hardware. These macros are defined in an include file selected by CONFIG_DEBUG_LL_INCLUDE (search arch/arm/Kconfig.debug for it). In case of the Versatile board CONFIG_DEBUG_LL_INCLUDE is defined as arch/arm/include/debug/pl01x.S, where in fact you find those macros.

Comment: Thank you , i saw the patch for ARCH_MULTIPLATFORM but i dint understand how it was implemented in generic way now i got it.

Comment: Any input on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36621505/debugging-linux-kernel-using-gdb-in-qemu-unable-to-hit-function-or-given-adress